# How to combine time into a variable

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I have an Arduino Uno project which is recording student attendance using fingerprint sensor. So when sensor found a match, the serial monitor will be printing out Student ID and current time like this:

```
    DateTime now;
    void setup()
      {
          ...
      }
        
    void loop()
      {
          .....
          //found a match
          Serial.print("Found ID #");
          Serial.println(finger.fingerID);
          Serial.print("Time->");
          Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
          Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
          Serial.print(':');
          Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
      }
```

Sample result will be:

```
Found ID#1
Time-> 18:11:54
```

I would like to store the time into a variable and print it out instead of printing hour, minute, and second separately. How can I do that???

I have tried to do like this as below but I'm getting an error, I would like to store it as a string. How can I do that?

```
string time = now.hour() + ':' + now.minute() + ':' + now.second();
```

Comment: It's going to be more efficient to print piece by piece. Because it constructs the text straight into the output buffer instead of needing to copy it over.

Comment: Hint: If you want to do some calculations or store a timestamp the data type `time_t` is a better choice. It is defined as seconds since midnight Jan 1 1970 (aka unix time). For more details see https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/blob/master/TimeLib.h#L21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `snprintf` for this:

```
char timeString[9];

snprintf(timeString, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
Serial.println(timeString);
```

By using a format string like this you are taking into account time portions < 10 (like 7 minutes and 23 seconds past 3 am, which would otherwise be 3:7:23) by padding the time with leading zeroes where needed.

Comment: Damn, you were three minutes quicker with the same solution.
Replacing `9` with `sizeof timeString` could be useful in case he ever wants to include more data into his time stamp.

Comment: Could be - as long as timeString is in the same (or greater) scope and not a pointer passed to a function :)

Comment: @Majenko Do you familiar with python or firebase? Cause I would like to send the output to the python code, for the python code itself will catch the output and push it to firebase real time database. I refer to this [website](https://muhd-lokman.weebly.com/projects) , I made the output like this `Serial.println("{'SID':"+ String(finger.fingerID) +",'time':"+ String(timeString) +"}");` but I don't know how to catch it in my python

Comment: I loathe python with a passion, and I have never heard of firebase.

Comment: @Majenko It's ok. I do the same thing to date. But I can display date like this`2018/11/`. Day cannot display, what happened?

Comment: Did you give enough room in your string?